# How to resize a window in MacOS App (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I need to create a Mac OS App. The idea is detect when the user moves the window with the mouse. When I know which window is I need to resize.

I have this code.

Active Window
In this struct I store the information for the Windows

```
struct ActiveWindow {
   let frame: CGRect
   let applicationName: String
   let windowId: Int

   init(frame: CGRect, applicationName: String, windowId: Int) {
      self.frame = frame.flippedScreenBounds
      self.applicationName = applicationName
      self.windowId = windowId
   }

   var isFocus: Bool {
       return applicationName.caseInsensitiveCompare("ReSize") == .orderedSame
   }
}
```

Windows List
Here I get an array for all windows opened into the OS

```
struct WindowList {
    static func allWindows() -> [ActiveWindow] {
         let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
         let windowsListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGMainDisplayID()) // This is the current windows
         let infoList = windowsListInfo as! [[String: Any]]
         return infoList.filter { $0["kCGWindowLayer"] as! Int == 0 }
            .map { ActiveWindow(
            frame: CGRect(x: ($0["kCGWindowBounds"] as! [String: Any])["X"] as! CGFloat,
                   y: ($0["kCGWindowBounds"] as! [String: Any])["Y"] as! CGFloat,
                   width: ($0["kCGWindowBounds"] as! [String: Any])["Width"] as! CGFloat,
                   height: ($0["kCGWindowBounds"] as! [String: Any])["Height"] as! CGFloat),
            applicationName: $0["kCGWindowOwnerName"] as! String,
            windowId: $0["kCGWindowNumber"] as! Int)}
}

    static func window(at point: CGPoint) -> ActiveWindow? {
       let list = allWindows()
       return list.filter{ $0.frame.contains(point) }.first
   }
}
```

This is my ViewController

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private lazy var windowMain: NSWindow = self.view.window!
    private var highlightWindowController: HighlighWindowController?
    private var currentView: ActiveWindow?
    private var mouseLocation: NSPoint = NSEvent.mouseLocation {
       didSet {
           if let window = WindowList.window(at: mouseLocation), !window.isFocus {
               self.currentView = window
               highlight(window: window)
           } else {
               removeHighlight()
           }
       }
}
```

Into my viewDidLoad register the mouse event.
The idea is get the all information about the windows when the user passes the course over the window

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerMouseEvents()
        
    }
```

```
    private func registerMouseEvents() {
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) {
            self.mouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation
            return $0
        }
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) { _ in
            self.mouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation
        }
    }
```

This is my first approach.

Comment: Your question title is how to resize a window, but the text of your question seems to be about detecting when a window is moved and which one.  Could you please clarify exactly what you are asking for help with?